# RALLY API: Could not set value for Tags: Cannot use type ObjectReference in attribute Tags

Tags: soap, rally

I am trying to create a new story in Rally.

Using: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.40/RallyService
Below is the code

```
    var parentStory = rallyService.query(Workspace, Projs["xxx"], true, true,                "HierarchicalRequirement", query, "", true, 1, 20).Results[0] as HierarchicalRequirement;
    var tag = new Tag[1];
    tag[0] = new Tag()
    {
       Archived = true,
       ArchivedSpecified = true,
       CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
       CreationDateSpecified = true,
       Name = tagName,
    };

    var childStory = new HierarchicalRequirement
    {
      Name = feedback.FeedBackSubject,
      Description = feedback.FeedBackDescription,
      Parent = parentStory,
      Owner = parentStory.Owner,
      Tags = tag
    };
    return rallyService.create(childStory);
```

I am getting the following error: Could not set value for Tags: Cannot use type ObjectReference in attribute Tags

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use the REST endpoints rather than SOAP but I would guess that you'll need to create your tag first before you reference it in the story you are creating.  I think the error is due to the fact that the tag being passed in the array doesn't have a ref.